# Trigger is not firing from Test Class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, apex

I have tried to search up on this for a while now but couldn't find any answer to my question... I have wrote a simple trigger that when an Account record is moved out of view (Moved out of view = true), then all the contacts associated with that specific account will be automatically marked as moved out of view (Moved out of view = true). Trigger works in sandbox and also before this incident, I was able to deploy this into production, but now as I was trying to add onto the same existing test class, I have noticed through System.assertEquals() that the trigger is not firing... Can someone please help explain what's going on? Thanks in advance...

*Trigger:*

```
    trigger moveContactsOutOfView on Account (After Update) {
    if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){
  set<String> notAccId = New Set<String>();     
  set<String> accId = New Set<string>();
  List<Contact> conUpdate = new List<Contact>();
  List<Contact> con1Update = new list<Contact>();
  List<AccountTeamMember> d1 = new List<AccountTeamMember>();

      for (Account a1: trigger.new){
      if (a1.ID != null && a1.Move_out_of_view__c == True){
          accId.Add(a1.ID);
          }
      else {
        notAccId.add(a1.ID);
        }
      }

  LIST<Contact> cY = [SELECT AccountID, LastModifiedById FROM Contact WHERE AccountID In: AccId];
  LIST<Contact> cN = [SELECT AccountID, LastModifiedById FROM Contact WHERE AccountID In: notAccId];
  List<AccountTeamMember> toBeDeleted =[SELECT ID, LastModifiedById FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountID In: AccId];

       for (Account a1: trigger.new){
            for (Contact c1:cY){
                if (c1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006xdMm' && c1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wnoE' && c1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wsIm'){
                    c1.Move_out_of_view__c = True;
                    conUpdate.add(c1);
                }
            }
            for (Contact c2:cN){
                if (c2.LastModifiedById != '00500000006xdMm'&& c2.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wnoE' && c2.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wsIm'){
                    c2.Move_out_of_view__c = False;
                    con1Update.add(c2);
                }
            }
       }
          for (AccountTeamMember t1:toBeDeleted){
                if (t1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006xdMm' && t1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wnoE' && t1.LastModifiedById != '00500000006wsIm'){
                    d1.add(t1);
                }
          }

update conUpdate;
update con1Update;
delete d1;
    }
}
```

*test class:*

```
    @isTest
public class TestPrimaryLiaisonCount2{
    static testMethod void insertNewContact(){

    //NEW Account record
    Account ACC = new Account();
    ACC.recordtypeID = '012000000000j8S';
    ACC.Name = 'Liu Inc';
    ACC.Industry = 'Advertising';
    ACC.NumberOfEmployees = 500;
    ACC.Center__c = 'Full Service';
    ACC.Move_out_of_view__c = False;
    insert ACC;

    string accId = ACC.id;

    //NEW Contact record for 'ACC'
    Contact ACDC = new Contact();
    ACDC.FirstName = 'Testing';
    ACDC.LastName = 'DEV';
    ACDC.Primary_Liaison__c = 'Center';
    ACDC.AccountID = ACC.Id;
    insert ACDC;

    ACDC = [SELECT Id, AccountID, Move_out_of_view__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountID =: accId limit 1];
    system.assertEquals(false, ACDC.Move_out_of_view__c);

    ACC.Move_out_of_view__c = True;
    update ACC;

    ACDC = [SELECT Id, AccountID, Move_out_of_view__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountID =: accId limit 1];
    system.assertEquals(true, ACDC.Move_out_of_view__c);
    }
 }
```

UPDATE - checkRecursive class:

```
public Class checkRecursive{
    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce(){
    if(run){
     run=false;
     return true;
    }else{
        return run;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of: checkRecursive.runOnce()

Comment: Hi dphil - I have added the checkRecursive class in my original post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Confirmed in a deleted answer comment thread that the test is being run using a different User ID than the 3 the trigger excludes.

Comment: dphil - I have just taken out of the checkRecursive call in the trigger and the test class passed, but i know that this is going to cause recursive issues later on... How can I keep calling checkRecursive and still able to fire/invoke the trigger from test class? Is that possible??

Comment: @MarkLiu Are there other places in code that calls your checkRecursive?  Like does the insert call it or any of the Contact triggers?

Comment: @dphil Yes, there's another contact trigger that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to change your recursive class then:

```
public Class checkRecursive{
  public static boolean run = true;
  public static boolean runOnce(){
  if(run){
     run = false;
     return true;
    }else{
        return run;
    }
  }
}
```

Then at the end of your test class:

```
ACC.Move_out_of_view__c = True;
checkRecursive.run = true;
update ACC;
```

Your contact class is setting it and you have nothing that resets it.  You could add like a reset method instead of making the variable public.  I just did that for simplicity.